# update query from array

Tags: php

i want to update query from array.the problem is when i ran the code, the updated data in the database just the first data..

example..

the array consist of integer type = [1,2]

when i ran the code, the data in the database just ran the first data (only 1)..how can i fix this?

**PHP file**

```
$query_edit_paket = "select nama_menu from menu where id_menu = 149 ";
        $query_exec_edit_paket = mysql_query($query_edit_paket) or die(mysql_error());  
        $nama_menu_query = reset(mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec_edit_paket));

     $_fbexclude = mysql_query("select id_paket from detail_paket where menu_paket = '$nama_menu_query' ");
    $fbexcludearray = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($_fbexclude)) {
      $fbexcludearray[] = $row['id_paket'];
    }

    $excludes = implode(',', $fbexcludearray);
    echo $excludes;

    for($i=0;$i<count($excludes);$i++)  
    {           
        if($excludes != "")  
        {           
            $strSQL = "update paket set ketersediaan_paket ='kosong' ";  
            $strSQL .="WHERE id_paket = '$excludes' ";  
            $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        }
    }
```

thanks!!

Comment: Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IN`

change

```
$strSQL .="WHERE id_paket = '$excludes' ";
```

to

```
$foo = '';
for($i=0; $i < count($fbexcludearray); $i++){
  $foo.= $i == 0? $fbexcludearray[$i]: ','.$fbexcludearray[$i];
}
    $strSQL .="WHERE id_paket IN ($foo) ";
```

Comment: sorry, after looking at your code again, the array that I should have used is fbexcludearray.  Try the code now

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, you don't need the loop: `for($i=0;$i<count($excludes);$i++)` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to print your $strSQL you would see that your query would be something like this

```
update paket set ketersediaan_paket ='kosong' WHERE id_paket = '1,2'
```

Which is not the query you want. What you want is more something like this

```
update paket set ketersediaan_paket ='kosong' WHERE id_paket = '1' OR WHERE id_paket = '2'
```

So you need to restructure your for loop or change your query.

Comment: no..i want to run the query many times depends on how many data in the array list..if the array have 2 data it will run the query twice with different data in the query..just like :`update paket set ketersediaan_paket ='kosong' WHERE id_paket = '1'` and again with the second data : `update paket set ketersediaan_paket ='kosong' WHERE id_paket = '2'`..

Comment: Than what you need to do is forget about the implode and use a 'foreach' over $fbexcludearray. You are doing 'count' over string, and it always returns 1, so that's why you are only running one query.